# Section and subsection numbers are reversed with Hebrew babel

Tags: babel, right-to-left

I use latex with the `babel` package to write my assignments in university in Hebrew, which is an RTL language. Unfortunately, I found that my current setup causes the numbers of sections and subsections to be displayed in reverse order:

[image]

I couldn't figure out how to make it display correctly. If we use Hebrew letters for numbering, it makes sense they would be displayed from right to left, but with numbers, it looks weird and confusing. How can I make the numbers display correctly?
In this example it should produce:

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.2.1
1.2.2
1.2.3
```

Here's the code that produces this example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=counters tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}[ItalicFont=*-Regular, ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3}]{Assistant}

\usepackage{xpatch}
% Fix RTL direction for `underline`
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\underline{$\@@underline}{\bgroup\bbl@nextfake$\@@underline}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\underline{$\relax}{$\egroup\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{נושא ראשון}
\subsection{תת נושא כלשהו}
\subsection{תת נושא נוסף}
\subsubsection{חלק ראשון של תת נושא}
\subsubsection{חלק שני}
\subsubsection{חלק שלישי}
\end{document}
```

I use the font [Assistant](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Assistant) and I compile with LuaLateX.

Comment: `layout = counters` should not be used with `bidi = basic`.

Comment: Or to be more precise, this output is as documented in babel's manual.

Comment: Thank you. It solved the issue. If you could write this as an answer, I will accept it.